# Why Linux kernel ticker is 100Hz but monitor refresh rate can be 60Hz

Tags: kernel

I'm reading the "Linux Kernel Development" by Robert Love. in the Chapter 11 "Timers and Time Management" he mentioned that:

> The kernel defines the value in <asm/param.h>.The tick rate has a
> frequency of HZ hertz and a period of 1/HZ seconds. For example, by
> default the x86 architecture defines HZ to be 100.Therefore, the timer
> interrupt on i386 has a frequency of 100HZ and occurs 100 times per
> second (every one-hundredth of a second, which is every 10
> milliseconds). Other common values for HZ are 250 and 1000,
> corresponding to periods of 4ms and 1ms, respectively.

I'm thinking that the monitor refresh should be also a timer-based event, but the refresh rate is 60Hz or 120Hz, seems this value can not be divided by 100,250 or 1000.

Comment: monitor refresh rate is not always 60 Hz ... why should the two frequencies be related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: The OS tick rate is independent of monitor refresh rate. Both control separate factors.

The OS tick rate defines how often the timer interrupt fires. This interrupt enables the OS to run its scheduling algorithm. Every OS tick, the currently executing task is interrupted, and the OS starts running. Here, the OS decides which task should be run during the following tick (this is called scheduling) and resumes that task. Effectively, the timer interrupt ensures the timeline below. As you can see, once a task is scheduled, it has 10ms to run uninterrupted.

> 10ms TaskA, OS scheduling, 10ms TaskB, OS scheduling, 10ms TaskC, .....

Supposing that one of these tasks is responsible for drawing frames to your monitor (say its a display server like X, or a game), it is responsible for using the time that it runs on the core to generate the frame (which is what is displayed on the screen) and write it to the framebuffer. The display controller (HDMI, DP) is responsible for regularly reading the frame from the framebuffer and sending it to the monitor.

As you can see, the OS tick rate and the monitor refresh rate are not connected. One determines how often the OS does scheduling, the other determines how often frames are drawn on a monitor. We can show how these are decoupled by looking at two extremes:

- Image slideshow The display server can write the image to the framebuffer once, and then sleep until the image needs to be changed (say once every 5seconds). Meanwhile, the display controller will continue to read the same image from the framebuffer and refresh the monitor at 60Hz.
- High FPS game (say 300hz). Every 10ms, 3 frames will be generated and displayed. Within 1 tick, the application will update the framebuffer 3 times. Suppose that the monitor is still 60Hz. Then the display controller will only read every 5th generated frame when it needs to send a frame to the monitor.

Hope this makes sense. I am not a graphics programmer, but I know some basics.

Comment: thank you!! the best and super clear answer!